# How Return Name Table From SQLSTRING

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

How can return the name of the table of inter SQLSTRING, for example:

SELECT * FROM TABLE1

THEN RETURN = (TABLE1)

SELECT ID , JOB FROM TABLE1

THEN RETURN = (TABLE1)

Comment: Could you clarify what it is you want? The question is a bit unclear as it is.

Comment: It's not even clear if this is a sql question or VB.NET, do you want extract the table-name of a sql-string or do you want to know the source of a record (f.e. from a `UNION ALL`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear. If you want to use a `UNION`  and you have to know the source of the record. You can add a column:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.JOB, Source = 'Table1' 
FROM TABLE1 T1

UNION ALL

SELECT T2.ID, T2.JOB, Source = 'Table2' 
FROM TABLE2 T2
```

If you instead want to extract the table-name(s) from a sql-string:

```
Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1"
Dim matches = Regex.Matches(sql, "(?<=from|join)(\s+\w+\b)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Dim tableNames = matches.Cast(Of Match)().Select(Function(m) m.Value.TrimStart()).ToList()

Console.Write(String.Join(",", tableNames)) ' TABLE1
```

Comment: Howwwwwwwwwwww , Very Very Goooooood , Thank You Tim

Comment: Thank you my brother very cool
But how do you know you are among ordinary or special, such as inter ( sum , avrg,count, .... )